# Min number of Elements To generate all other elements using xor

Tags: algorithm

I have n integers `a_1, ..., a_n`. I want to pick the minimum number from all of them whose xor forms others.

For example, consider `[1,2,3]`, `1^3=2` so you don't need `2` in the array. So you can remove it. To end up with `[1,3]`. So the min number of elements is `2` and they can form all  the original elements in the array by xoring any 2 of them. Would a greedy approach work here? or DP?

Edit: To explain what I am thinking. A greedy approach I thought about was due to the fact that if `a^b=c` then `a^c=b` and `b^c=a`. First I delete all duplicates. then I would first in the beginning list all the pairs that each element can pair up with to form another element in the array. It takes `O(n^3)` for preprocessing. Then I pick the element with the least contribution and I delete it and subsequently subtract 1 from each of the other elements. I repeat this until all elements have <=2 pairs. and I stop. This would also take `O(n^3)` for a total of `O(n^3)`. Does this greedy approach work? Is there a DP way to do it?

Comment: The question's not clear. Are you allowed to take the xor of more than two of the elements in your reduced set?

Comment: No. Only 2 are allowed

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? I've added details of what I've tried so far

Comment: Do you know there's an efficient solution? It seems like it might easily be NP complete.

Comment: @PaulHankin This was in a competition and n was bounded by 50 so I don't think it would be NP-Complete (2^50 operations would never terminate in 2 seconds)

Comment: I think an O(n^3 or 4) is the worst for this case

Comment: Write each integer in binary form as a vector.  Example 23 becomes [1, 0, 1, 1, 1].   Combine all the vectors together to form a matrix over GF(2).  Then what you are seeking is the smallest subset of linear independent vectors in the matrix.  Use linear algebra.

Comment: @TheGreatContini how do you find the smallest subset of l.i.vecs? The maximum is the rank, but what is the minimum?!

Comment: I should have said the largest subset of linear independent vectors.   My sloppiness.  Anyway, it is found by Gaussian elimination, similar as to @kfx answered.

Answer (score 0):

If n is bounded by 50 I think backtracking should work.

Suppose at some step we have already selected a subset **S** of numbers (that should produce all the others) and want to include a new number to that subset.
Then we can do the following:

- Consider all remaining numbers **R** and include in **S** all numbers that can't be produced by others (in **S** and **R**)
- Include in **S** a random (or "best" in some way) number from **R**
- Remove from **R** all numbers that can be produced by those in updated **S**

Also you should keep track of the current best solution and cut off all the branches that won't allow to get a better result.